# Cordova inappbrowser looses event handlers when system browser opens

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, inappbrowser

I have been pulling my hair out for days trying to solve this problem so really hoping someone has a solution!

The problem exists only in Android, iOS seems to work fine.

The app is displaying a website using the inappbrowser. When a link external to the website is clicked I want to launch the selected link in the system browser and then ensure that the inappbrowser page does not change. I have this working using the code below. The problem I have is that after the system browser has opened, all my events (loadstart, loadstop) no longer work and therefore if another external link is selected it now is not detected in the loadstart event and opens in the inappbrowser.

If I simply comment out the window.open(url, '_system'); line in the loadstart event everything continues to work as it should but obviously the external link does not open in the system browser.

```
launchBrowser: function (url) {
    app.inAppBrowserRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', app.browserOptions);
    app.inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('loadstart', function (event) {
        var url = event.url;
        // Determine if this is an external link that should be launched in the system browser.
        if (url.toLowerCase().indexOf(app.portalUrl.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
            //External link, launch in system browser.
            window.open(url, '_system');
            app.setInappBrowserUrl(app.previousUrl);
        }
    });
    app.inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('loadstop', function (event) {
        app.previousUrl = event.url;
    });
},
```

Function to override the inappbrowser page.

```
setInappBrowserUrl: function (overrideUrl) {
    app.inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({
        code: "window.location = '" + overrideUrl + "';"
    }, function () {
        //alert("Redirected!");
    });
}
```

I have a crude workaround that involves calling launchBrowser() with the url I want to display, but the problem is I loose all the history so when you press the back button the inappbrowser closes.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: are you using the `hardwareback` option? It must be set to `yes`

Comment: I am using the hardwareback option, and this is all working as expected i.e. in the work around it closes the inappbrowser because there is no previous page to go to, because the inappbrowser has been re-initialised. I only want to use the work around as a last resort.

Comment: i've got the same problem on iOS :( have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The InAppBrowser eventHandler needs to be reinitialized once cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_system'); or window.open(url, '_system'); is called within the eventhandler. In your code, add a reference to window.open(url, '_system'); and add eventHandler as follow:

```
    function loadStartEventHandler(event){
    var url = event.url;
    // Determine if this is an external link that should be launched in the system browser.
        if (url.toLowerCase().indexOf(app.portalUrl.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
          //External link, launch in system browser.
          //window.open(url, '_system');
          //reference the new InAppBrowser
          var ref = window.open(url, '_system');
          //reassign the event handler
          ref.addEventListener('loadstart', loadStartEventHandler);

          app.setInappBrowserUrl(app.previousUrl);
        }
    }
    app.inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('loadstart', loadStartEventHandler);
```

### The bug has been submitted to cordova apache. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13198